# Bluetooth headset not detected by pulseaudio - OpenSUSE Thumbleweed

Tags: opensuse, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my bluetooth headset to my OpenSUSE Thumbleweed (KDE Plasma). 
The Bluetooth connection works, but I can not see my headset appearing on the audio devices.

Here are the logs of `journalctf -f` during the connection & disconnection.

```bash
Jul 16 09:42:05 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[843]: src/profile.c:record_cb() Unable to get Hands-Free Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
Jul 16 09:42:05 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[843]: src/device.c:load_gatt_db() No cache for 4C:87:5D:DD:F1:3A
Jul 16 09:42:05 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[843]: Device is already marked as connected
Jul 16 09:42:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snapperd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 16 09:42:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: snapperd.service: Consumed 1.699s CPU time.
Jul 16 09:42:06 localhost.localdomain kernel: input: Le grand bleu (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input22
Jul 16 09:42:06 localhost.localdomain systemd-logind[882]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event18 (Le grand bleu (AVRCP))


Jul 16 09:42:12 localhost.localdomain dbus-daemon[844]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.61" (uid=1000 pid=3078 comm="/usr/bin/wireplumber") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.4" (uid=0 pid=843 comm="/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd")
```

I have tried to restart pulseaudio, to start it for the user, system-wide. Nothing worked.

Comment: `System settings -> Audio` should list the headset. You'll then just need to mark it as enabled and perhaps change a couple of other things.

Comment: Not appearing, neither in `pacmd list-sinks` @Bib

Comment: Finally, 
I managed to get my sound back switching from pulseaudio to pipewire using this forum tips: https://lists.opensuse.org/archives/list/factory@lists.opensuse.org/thread/VNROKVXVFICDVJXCXZQIB6UYHYVGFGFK/